# Distribution of Combination of Amounts by Group

Tags: r

I have a table that looks like this:

| Id | Types |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | A |
| 3 | B |
| 4 | A |
| 4 | B |
| 4 | B |

What I would like to do is 1. count for every ID the amount of A's and B's it has. 2. Compute the distribution of every combination of the amounts of A and B.

So at the end of step 2 I should have the table:

| Amount of A | Amount of B | Number of Different IDs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 |

How can this be achieved?

Thank you.

Comment: It is not clear about your expected output.  How did you get the 1 1 2?  Is it for each Id

Comment: In the first row: The 1 and 1 are a combination of number of A's and number of B's, while the 2 is the number of different ideas that have this amount of A and B (IDs 2 and 3).

Comment: how do you define a combination here

Comment: Quick question: how do you want it to look after **Step 1**? A table with the headers | `Id` | `Type` | `Amount` |, or a table with the headers | `Id` | `Amount of A` | `Amount of B` |?  Keep in mind that the latter is liable to get progressively wider, as each additional type (..., `"C"`, `"D"`, ..., `"ZZ"`, ...) would add an additional column (...| `Amount of C` | `Amount of D` | ... |`Amount of ZZ`| ...). Once you let me know, I can update my [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67942434) with separate `step_1` and `step_2` variables, to hold separately the results of each step.

Comment: Did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67942434) end up working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


# ...
# Code to generate your original table: "your_table".
# ...


result <- your_table %>%
  # Count the amount of each type for each Id.
  group_by(Id) %>% count(Types) %>% ungroup() %>%
  # "Pivot" the Types column, such that each type (here "A" and "B") gets its
  # own column (here "Amount of A" and "Amount of B") to hold its amount (as
  # calculated right above).
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(Id, Types),
              names_from = Types, names_prefix = "Amount of ",
              values_from = n) %>%
  # For each combination of amounts among those pivoted columns (ie. all the
  # columns except "Id"), count how many distinct IDs there are.
  group_by(across(-c(Id))) %>%
  summarize("Number of Different IDs" = n_distinct(Id)) %>% ungroup()
  

# Print the result.
result
```

Given the example of `your_table` that you provided

```
your_table <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Id, ~Types,
  1,    "A",
  1,    "A",
  1,    "A",
  1,    "B",
  2,    "A",
  2,    "B",
  3,    "A",
  3,    "B",
  4,    "A",
  4,    "B",
  4,    "B"
)
```

you should get the following `result`:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  `Amount of A` `Amount of B` `Number of Different IDs`
          <int>         <int>                     <int>
1             1             1                         2
2             1             2                         1
3             3             1                         1
```